# tidyeval unquote user created variable for subsequent usage

Tags: r, tidyeval

I'm having trouble unquoting variable created by a function (with a prefix if it matters) for subsequent usage later in the function. enquo doesn't seem to work, but I'm sure I'm doing something dumb. (I'm new to tidyeval.

```
library(survey)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data(api)

names( apistrat)
apistrat <- apistrat %>% as_survey_design(ids = 1, fpc = fpc)

test_func <- function(var) {
  apistrat %>% mutate(col.grad=as.factor(col.grad)) %>% group_by(col.grad) %>% 
    summarise("mean_{{var}}" := survey_mean({{ var }}, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
    mutate("ub_mean_{{var}}" :=
             "mean_{{var}}_se" * 1.96 + "mean_{{var}}") #Think I need to unquote for this line so it's evaluated
}
test_func(meals)

#Tried this, which didn't work
test_func <- function(var) {
  apistrat %>% mutate(col.grad=as.factor(col.grad)) %>% group_by(col.grad) %>% 
    summarise("mean_{{var}}" := survey_mean({{ var }}, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
    mutate("ub_mean_{{var}}" :=
             enquo("mean_{{var}}_se") * 1.96 + enquo("mean_{{var}}")) #Think I need to unquote for this line so it's evaluated
}
test_func(meals)

#Desired output
test_func <- function(var) {
  apistrat %>% mutate(col.grad=as.factor(col.grad)) %>% group_by(col.grad) %>% 
    summarise("mean_{{var}}" := survey_mean({{ var }}, na.rm=TRUE)) 
}
test_func(meals) %>% mutate(ub_mean_meals=mean_meals_se*1.96+mean_meals) #Want this part in the function
```

Comment: Try to work outside of dplyr when it gets hairy (i.e. pull out the new vectors from the data frame). You can also use `as_label(enquo(arg))` to create a textual summary of an expression that you can then manipulate as you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge is wanting to manipulate variable names, which is best done with string arithmetic instead of expression arithmetic. One approach is to create a wrapper that converts symbols to strings, splices them together and then converts the result back to a symbol:

```
library( tidyverse )
lbl <- function(...) {ensyms(...) %>% reduce(str_c) %>% sym}
```

You can then use this wrapper to create new labels on the fly:

```
test_func <- function(var) {
    L1 <- lbl( mean_, {{var}} )
    L2 <- lbl( mean_, {{var}}, `_se` )
    L3 <- lbl( ub_mean_, {{var}} )

    apistrat %>% mutate(col.grad=as.factor(col.grad)) %>% group_by(col.grad) %>%
        summarise( !!L1 := survey_mean({{ var }}, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
        mutate( !!L3 := !!L2 * 1.96 + !!L1 )
}

test_func(meals)
# # A tibble: 48 x 4
#    col.grad mean_meals mean_meals_se ub_mean_meals
#    <fct>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#  1 0              51.5         7.71           66.6
#  2 2              96           0.916          97.8
#  3 3              83.9         6.45           96.6
#  4 4              96           2.77          101.
# ...
```